# Safeguarding Cin When Using Unsigned Values

Tags: c++, user-input, unsigned, cin

In a program, I read in an unsigned long long, and that normally works fine. However, if someone decides to enter a negative number, The prompt, prints infinitely.

This is the part of my code, that it is relevant:

```
    unsigned long long betAmount = 0;
    cout << "You have " << chipCount << " chips currently!" << endl;
    cout << "How many chips would you like to bet?" << endl;
    cout << "Must be a whole number: ";
    cin >> betAmount;
```

It is pretty standard, unless given a negative.

Comment: Interesting -- I don't see that behavior: http://ideone.com/JmHllh

Comment: What prints infinitely?  The "Must be a whole number"?  When I repeat on my machine I just get garbage in 'betAmount', which is normal

Comment: I think it would be easiest to read a regular int and then check if it is positive.

Comment: @VaughnCato I need the space of an unsigned long though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `string` to get the input. Check the first byte. If it is a `unsigned`, use a `stringstream` to convert the string to `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Not sufficient. What if the user enters: "asdf"?  A safer alternative would be to use the likes of `boost::lexical_cast`, assuming performance isn't an issue (and reading user input from stdin, not likely an issue).